# git browse for Bitbucket repositories

Tags: git, shell, terminal, bitbucket

I want to have the [`git browse` feature](https://github.com/github/hub#git-browse) for Bitbucket repositories.

In my workflow, I work in the terminal with git and then I usually open to the same project on Bitbucket to do a pull request or review something, so I only need to open the working directory in the browser.

Assuming that I'm using OS X and I can open a url from the terminal with the open command:

```
$ open http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution, adding to the `bash_profile` the following lines:

```
function git_browse {
  if [ "$1" == "browse" ]; then
    local domain="$(git ls-remote --get-url | cut -c 5- | cut -d: -f1)"
    local url="$(git ls-remote --get-url | cut -c 5- | cut -d: -f2)"

    if [ "$domain" == "bitbucket.org" ]; then
      open https://bitbucket.org/$url
    else
      git "$@"
    fi
  else
    git "$@"
  fi
}

alias git="git_browse $*"
```

How do you improve it?